# Why changing to float-point value does't improve the speed?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, faq

I am testing the first tip of [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/) article

> Use floating-point numbers if you can, and use them early.

I've compared a pair codes and finding it's not helpful to use the float-point number during calculation. I don't understand why.

```
f[x_] := x^2;
Table[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100000}], {j, 1, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Result: 54.0099 sec.

```
f[x_] := x^2;
Table[Sum[f[i], {i, 1., 100000}], {j, 1, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Result: 54.6481 sec.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Why not `Do[Total[Range[1., 100000.]^2], 1000] // AbsoluteTiming` ?

Comment: Most of the time goes to summing either symbolically or perhaps element-wise, I am not sure which. COuld use `Compile` if you want to reduce memory use, or else "vectorize" e.g. as `sumSquares[n_] := Total[Range[n]^2]`.

Comment: I see substantially similar was posted while I was running tests...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, machine integers and machine floats will have similar speeds.  Integers will be a little faster, as long as numeric computation is the task.  The problem, or pitfall, with integers in *Mathematica* is that they are treated as exact expressions.  In complicated calculations, the integers may grow beyond machine size and division results in exact rationals; further, special functions, like `Sin[2]`, remain unevaluated and are treated as symbolic expressions.  When in a computation such non-machine values are introduce, instead of native CPU arithmetic, the software routines of *Mathematica* are invoked.  Naturally, the software routines are slower.

As symbolic software system, *Mathematica* can do some unexpected things, and it takes a while to learn them all.  Most iterative commands, like `Table`, `Sum`, `Map`, etc., will compile their expressions if the number of iterations is high enough (see `SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]` and scan  for options ending in "CompileLength").  [What can be compiled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) takes a long explanation.  In the present example, `f[i]` fails to be compiled, but its value `i^2` will be compiled.

```
(* OP's form -- slow, uncompiled *)
Table[Sum[f[i], {i, 1., 100000}], {j, 1, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {6.84558, Null}  *)
```

With f[i] evaluated via [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) or with `i^2` substituted directly, it is somewhat faster due to compilation of the summand:

```
Table[Sum[Evaluate@f[i], {i, 1., 100000}], {j, 1, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.04318, Null}  *)

Table[Sum[i^2, {i, 1., 100000}], {j, 1, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.04277, Null}  *)
```

With integers, it's even faster:

```
Table[Sum[Evaluate@f[i], {i, 1, 100000}], {j, 1, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.160928, Null}  *)

Table[Sum[i^2, {i, 1, 100000}], {j, 1, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.148675, Null}  *)
```

For real speed, use [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) and the vectorization of arithmetical operations and many functions. Integers are still faster than floats.

```
Table[Total[f[Range[1., 100000]]], {j, 1, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.071032, Null}  *)

Table[Total[f[Range[1, 100000]]], {j, 1, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.046477, Null}  *)
```

If the integers become bigger than machine integers (bigger than `2^63 - 1`), then the integer computation will slow down.

```
Table[Total[f[2^Range[1., 1000]]], {j, 1, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.336848, Null}  *)

Table[Total[f[2^Range[1, 1000]]], {j, 1, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.00608, Null}  *)
```

To see a bigger difference, consider the more complicated summand `f[i/(i + 1)]`, which won't be compilable in integers but will be compilable in floats:

```
Table[Sum[Evaluate@f[i/(i + 1)], {i, 1, 10000}], {j, 1, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {4.94459, Null}  *)

Table[Sum[Evaluate@f[i/(i + 1)], {i, 1., 10000}], {j, 1, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.31874, Null}  *)
```

Comment: Fun fact: on modern x86 hardware, FP division has better throughput than integer division (giving quotient/remainder).  So even if `i/(i+i)` was compiled into native machine code, or if you were doing this in C, you'd expect FP to be faster.  e.g. on Skylake, `vdivpd ymm` has one per 8 clock cycle throughput, and does a SIMD vector of four 64-bit `double` divisions in one asm instruction.  (http://agner.org/optimize/).  But 32-bit `idiv` has one per 6 cycle throughput for one integer division, or 64-bit has one per 24-90 cycle throughput.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's a good point. I was thinking of `i/(i + 1)` in terms of how *Mathematica* deals with it. For most integers `i`, the fraction `i/(i + 1)` will not be an integer, so *M* will represent it as a `Rational`.  I'm not sure how you would test it in *M*, but comparing `Quotient` and `Divide` on `num = Range[10^8]` and `num = N@Range[10^8]` resp., and `den = 1 + num`, I get that the integer division `Quotient[num, den]` is about 15% faster on my Ivy Bridge Core i7 and 20% faster on my Kaby Lake Core i7 (both Macbook Pros).

Answer (score 0):

I did your base case and got this;

```
f[x_] := x^2;
Table[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 100000}], {j, 1, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{145.3798581, Null}
```

Case 2 with 1. for i and got this;

```
{105.1217869, Null}
```

Case 3 with 1. and 100000. for i and got this;

```
{103.4749818, Null}
```

Case 4 with real i and changed f[x]=x*x

```
{90.511359, Null}
```

Case 5 with real i and used i*i in the Sum[], (i.e no f[x])

```
{6.0216106, Null}
```

Not sure what it all means because I am new to MMA but performance tuning is a black art.

NB: I am on version 8, if that matters.